# Pentagon circumscribes a circle. Prove that its area is $5r^2\tan(36^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose that a regular pentagon circumscribes a circle of radius r.
We are supposed to show proof, using the trigonometric area of the triangle 
(1/2)b*h*sin(36°) that the area of the pentagon is 5r^2tan(36°)

In this specific problem, the radius have replaced b and h. The pentagon has 5 sides, so the 5 on the pentagon area is also checked out, and we're supposed to be using trig identities when necessary. But we're struggling on HOW to actually show proof that the result of the pentagon area will be 5r^2tan(36°), assuming what I explained.

I've been struggling on this for hours! My math tutors are also working on it. So your help is appreciated.

EDIT: Again, we're trying to go from A=1/2bh sin(36) to A=5r^2 tan (36). So I would prefer a complete walkthrough.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $ABCDE$ be the pentagon and $O$ be the center of the inscribed circle. Consider triangle $AOB,$ for example. It is isosceles, and can thus be divided into two right triangles, with either $A$ or $B,$ and $O$ as two vertices. The height is $r,$ the radius of the circle. The base is _____, and the total area of the pentagon is thus _____.

Answer (score 1):

The five isoscleles triangles have height $r$ and half the base length is $r\tan 36^\circ$ (as seen from the right triangles constituting the two halves of the isosceles triangle. Hence the area of the circumscribed pentagon is $5\cdot \frac 12\cdot r \cdot 2r\tan 26^\circ=5r^2\tan36^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

$ h=r$

Opposite  half side of regular pentagon length $= b/2 = r \cdot \tan (2 \pi /10 )$

Each triangle area is $ \frac12 \cdot  b \cdot r$

There are five of them.So..